# Sharepoint C# How to retrieve all pictures and their name by Title of Picture library

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Who knows about how to get the image by the Title of the Picture Library (List) using SP C #. Can guide me.

Hope everybody know about SharePoint can help me.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSOM to achive this, demo code is here: https://www.codesharepoint.com/csom/get-all-items-in-sharepoint-using-csom

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
 
using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://MyServer/sites/MySiteCollection"))
{
// clientcontext.Web.Lists.GetById - This option also can be used to get the list using List GUID
// This value is NOT List internal name
List targetList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("List Name");
 
// Optioanlly you can use overloaded method CreateAllItemsQuery(int rowlimits, params viewfields): where using "rowlimits" you can limit the number of rows returned and viewfields will return only specified fields in the result set
// This method will get all the items from all the folders and sub folders including folders and sub folders too
CamlQuery oQuery = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();
 
ListItemCollection oCollection = targetList.GetItems(oQuery);
clientContext.Load(oCollection);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
 
foreach (ListItem oItem in oCollection)
{
Console.WriteLine(oItem["Title"].ToString());
}
}
```

Comment: Can I ask more about the path of Image, In SharePoint, I see that each image uploaded will have its own link. So how to get it in C #, your demo code can do it?? Thanks

Comment: You could use oItem["FileRef"] property to get the image path